# ArrayAdapter for ImageView using AsyncTask to download the image

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have an ArrayAdapter and its getView method has something is this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //get object against selected list item
    book thisbook = getItem( position );
    ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.book, parent, false);
        viewHolder.bookImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bookImage);
        viewHolder.txtbookTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtbookTitle);
        //download image and set the bitmap for bookImage ImageView
        new DownloadImageService( viewHolder.bookImage ).execute( thisbook.getImageUrl() );
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.txtbookTitle.setText(thisbook.getbookTitle());
    viewHolder.bookImage = thisbook.getbookImage();
    viewHolder.txtbookId.setText(thisbook.getbookId());
    new DownloadImageService( viewHolder.bookImage ).execute( thisbook.getImageUrl() );
    return convertView;
```

}

Now, when I scroll down I load more items into my ArrayList of data and then call myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() and what happens is the book images are messed up i.e. the newly loaded item will have an image from another item which is already loaded into the list. e.g. if a book with id 1 is loaded already in the list and image is a.jpeg when scroll down the listview and load a new book say with id 10 although its image should be 10.JPEG but it has that a.jpeg with blongs to another book, its strange, not sure what I am doing wrong.

while debugging I have checked the input ArrayList for adapter and I can see all the books in the ArrayList perfectly as they should be.

Comment: Could you post whole `getView()`?

Comment: @neworld updated the question, thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post DownloadImageService? or you may look for lazy image loading utilities like: Picasso, glide or universal image loader. Hope that help!